# Sequentially index between a boolean vector in R

Tags: r, seq

The title says it.

my vector

```
TF <- c(F,T,T,T,F,F,T,T,F,T,F,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,F)
```

my desired output

```
[1] 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#with(rle(TF), sequence(lengths) * rep(values, lengths))
with(rle(TF), sequence(lengths) * TF) #Like Rich suggested in comments
# [1] 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0
```

Comment: `sequence(lengths) * TF` !!

Comment: Everyone gave great answers that I appreciate and will go over one by one but this one was the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `rle()` along with `sequence()`.

```
replace(TF, TF, sequence(with(rle(TF), lengths[values])))
# [1] 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0
```

`replace()` does the coercion for us.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `inverse.seqle` from `cgwtools`:

```
library(cgwtools)
SEQ = inverse.seqle(rle(TF)) 
SEQ[!TF] = 0
```

Or similar to @d.b's answer:

```
inverse.seqle(rle(TF))*TF

# [1] 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rleid`

```
library(data.table)
ave(TF, rleid(TF), FUN = seq_along)*TF
#[1] 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0
```

Answer (score 2):

By using base R

```
ave(cumsum(TF==FALSE), cumsum(TF==FALSE), FUN=seq_along)-1
 [1] 0 1 2 3 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0
```

Comment: `TF == FALSE` is more simply `!TF`.  Also, assigning `cumsum(!TF)`  first would be more efficient since you won't need to calculate it twice.

Comment: @RichScriven yeah , that is great suggestion , thank you !! :)